# How to create objects and allocate data only once in C++ to improve speed with octave .oct files?

Tags: c++, memory-usage

I have been coding some octave .oct files lately (C++), and for my purposes speed is of the essence.

It seems to me that creating C++ objects (in general) can take some time. I was wondering if there is some way to circumvent this? Maybe to somehow create a statically allocated object the first time the function is called and then to return it every time. Although I don't know how it could be possible to do this memory-safely.

It is safe to assume I want to return a sparse matrix object, and I know an upper bound on the number of nonzero elements, so that all the information required for creating the object once-and-for-all exists at first function call.

Just to create the object seems to take some 0.05 seconds but the overhead of calling oct file is only on magnitude 5e-5 seconds. That is a factor of a thousand which can be very impactful if the rest of the code is heavily optimized computational C-code which often runs faster than 1e-5 seconds.

Comment: Have you profiled the code and proved that it is indeed memory allocation/object construction? And not say the delay imposed by accessing data from a drive?

Comment: No secondary storage is accessed, well except whatever octave may do to load and prep .oct files.

Comment: So again, have you profiled the code to identify what is slowing it down? Are you hitting a lot of page faults? Are you performing a lot of locking/unlocking? Does the thread yield on this execution path?

Comment: @Kain0_0 no page faults, no locking, no thread yields. Very slow API calls (had same problem with Matlab and mex-programming) and constructing objects from C++ classes can take many times longer than the calculations the object is supposed to carry out. It is ridiculous how much overhead seems to be needed to construct objects from C++ classes.

Comment: I think this is simple a wrong statement. Creating objects in C++ is as fast as it could be, considering that you are dynamically allocating memory, and that is _pretty_ fast. Everything else is poor coding. Don't blame the language, profile your code and find the reason it is slow.

Comment: @Aganju It is no where near as fast as it could be. Allocating memory is slow as hell. It should be possible to avoid to do so if one wants to.

Comment: allocating memory is done by the OS, not by the language. and of course, you are able to avoid using it. it depends on your code design, not on the language you use.

Comment: @Aganju Preciiisely. That is my point with the whole question. To avoid asking OS for memory while running. Maybe ask once at first call (if necessary) and no more afterwards.

Comment: How is the sparse matrix internally organized in memory? Is it organized as a linked list? Linked list implies that each item requires its own allocation, which means the number of allocations will be proportional to the number of items, which will be slow.

Comment: @rwong seems it makes new allocations and copies all the data when it should be able to get away with just taking it over by pointing to a few places. I suppose if I overload it on my own in a new class it could work. But... the right way to do it would be to rewrite it correctly on my own like it should be done.

Comment: Linked list? What? Who would use that? For a sparse matrix application? Just.. why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How many objects do you have to create?

If it is just one object, then what @candied_orange said is the way to go.

If it is multiple objects, then I would suggest an object pool, which would be filled in a separate thread once it gets under a certain limit.

If it is a single threaded application and you need multiple objects, then I would also suggest an object pool, but you would allocate memory for multiple objects at once, and once it is consumed, allocate it again.

Comment: The difference in the appropriate cases for our different suggestions isn't so much "how many objects" but consumable vs persistent objects.  If there is a need to toss the object aside never to use it again then your object pool is preferable.

Comment: If the object is consumable (by which I assumed you meant read only, or an object with just methods to be invoked), then yes, your approach is the best. However, even if it is persistent (object needed to be manipulated with) if there is just one such object, then your approach with the singleton or DI would work. So, I guess, both criteria need to be taken into account.

Answer (score 4):

There are two patterns that cover this problem: Singleton and Pure Dependency Injection.

Singletons are widely maligned because they effectively become globals and thus have all the associated complications if you try to refactor or reuse code. But they still work as well as they ever did.

Pure Dependency Injection has you create your one shot objects in main (or the closest to it that your framework will let you get). The fancy people call that your composition root. Since main is called only once anything you build there is only built once. If you need something in different places you pass a reference (or pointer) into those different places. Done this way your one shots only get built once but can be passed anywhere. All without silly globals.  Only problem is now you have to actually allow that to be wired up. It's not free. It's work. But now things are explicit about what they need. And you only take the hit for constructing these objects once at the start of the program.

If you want to pay for it later, as needed, well you could go back to the Singleton pattern. It can cache the object. But if that global thing bugs you, well you can always inject factories that also know how to cache.